# Pegar um valor de um input sem submit

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Preciso guardar o valor um `input radio` para concatenar em um href depois, mas antes de fazer o submit.

Meu código do form:

```
 <form action="recuperarsenha.php" method="POST" onsubmit="displayWaitMessage()">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="labelemail">Email</label>
            <input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@example" autofocus required >
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
       <center>
            <input name="tipo" value="candidato" type="radio" checked> Candidato
            <input name="tipo" value="professor" type="radio"> Professor
            <input name="tipo" value="secretario" type="radio"> Secretaria
       </center>
       </div>
       <center>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href='../candidato/index.php'>Voltar</a>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Enviar">
       </center>
       </form>
```

Meu javaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        var x = document.getElementsByName("tipo");
        if(x == 'candidato'){
             var endereco = '../candidato/index.php';
        }else if(x == 'secretario'){
             var endereco = '../secretaria/index.php';
        }else if(x == 'professor'){
             var endereco = '../professor/index.php';
 </script>
```

Como pego essa `var endereco` e coloco no `<a class="btn btn-danger" href='../candidato/index.php'>Voltar</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode capturar o valor do endereço toda vez que o radio mudar e já mudar o valor do href usando o 'attr' do jquery.

```
$('input[name=tipo]').change(function(){
      var endereco = "../"+$('input[name=tipo]:checked').val()+"/index.php";
      $('#link').attr("href",endereco);
    });
```

Aqui você pode ver um pouco do evento change (dispara sempre que ocorre uma mudança): https://api.jquery.com/change/

e aqui você pode ver um pouco sobre o attr do jquery, usado para fazer mudanças de atributos, ele recebe como primeiro argumento o atributo a ser mudado, e em segundo o novo valor do atributo: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

Com um JQuery seria bem mais facil, mas com parece nao estar utilizando vai uma solucao alternativa.

O lance e voce conseguir identificar qual radio esta selecionado `checked`

```js
var tipos = document.getElementsByName("tipo")
var endereco = ''

tipos.forEach(function(tipo){
  if(tipo.checked){
  
    if(tipo.value=='candidato'){
      endereco = '../candidato/index.php';
    }else if(tipo.value=='secretario'){
      endereco = '../secretaria/index.php';
    }else if(tipo.value=='professor'){
      endereco = '../professor/index.php';
    }
  }
});


document.getElementById('link').href = endereco

console.log(document.getElementById('link').href)
```

```html
<form action="recuperarsenha.php" method="POST" onsubmit="displayWaitMessage()">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="labelemail">Email</label>
            <input name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@example" autofocus required >
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
       <center>
            <input name="tipo" id="candidato" value="candidato" type="radio" checked> Candidato
            <input name="tipo" id="professor" value="professor" type="radio"> Professor
            <input name="tipo" id="secretario" value="secretario" type="radio"> Secretaria
       </center>
       </div>
       <center>
       <div class="g-recaptcha"  style="padding-bottom: 10px; " data-sitekey="6LddhRIUAAAAAH6tQ5Sqbco_LF7zWoN3ZXPdODQV"></div>
       <a class="btn btn-danger" id="link" href='../candidato/index.php'>Voltar</a>
       <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary">
       </center>
       </form>
```

Existe varias outras formas de se fazer isso, deixei assim para ficar o mais proximo do codigo que voce ja tem.

Comment: Deu certo haha 
Realmente Jquery é muito mais fácil, utilizei com jquery, mas testei e o seu também funcionou. Obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

Pode obter o mesmo resultado do que seria com jQuery:

```js
const anchor = document.querySelector('a')

for(const item of document.querySelectorAll('input[name=tipo]')){
  item.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if(item.checked)
      anchor.setAttribute('href', `../${item.value}/index.php`)
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <center>
    <input name="tipo" value="candidato" type="radio" checked> Candidato
    <input name="tipo" value="professor" type="radio"> Professor
    <input name="tipo" value="secretario" type="radio"> Secretaria
  </center>
</div>

<a href='../candidato/index.php'>Voltar</a>
```